# How can i delete a file with only the content uri?

Tags: java, android

Before API 29 i deleted files with the path i got from `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA` column which is now deprecated.

**Now i do it like this**

```
song.setData(ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID))));
```

But this returns a **content uri** which looks like this:  `content://media/external/audio/media/92079`

Before i just did `file.delete` for files on internal storage and `documentFile.delete()` for files on external storage.

But now that i only have the **content uri** and not a path to the media file it doesn't work anymore.

So how can i delete files without relying on the `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA` for a path to the media file?

**Full code which worked before API 29 and using the DATA column**

```
private void deleteFile(Uri uri, File file){
        if (file.delete()){
            Log.i(TAG,"internal delete!");
            return;
        }
        if (getActivity() != null && file.exists()) {
            DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getActivity(), uri);
            String filename = file.getName();
            try {
                getActivity().getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "SecurityException caught when deleting FilePath!", e);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "fileName: " + filename);
            if (pickedDir != null) {
                DocumentFile documentFile = pickedDir.findFile(filename);
                if (documentFile != null && documentFile.exists()) {
                    if (documentFile.delete()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Delete successful");
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Delete unsuccessful");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```